# Get Instance EC2 Status using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I want to create simple Lambda script that return instances status.
For example for instances that not running will return false, and if the instances  is running will return true.

How can I do it using lambda?

Comment: There's really nothing AWS Lambda specific about this question. You just need to look into how to accomplish this task using the AWS SDK, and then use the AWS SDK in your Lambda function.

Comment: Lambda function are written using nodejs/python/Java/C#. Which language are you planning to use.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Python, you can use boto3's `describe-instance-status` function (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instance_status)